# Distinct Count when using Case When

Tags: sql-server, distinct, case-when

I am having trouble getting the correct distinct count when using case when and distinct in SQL Server.

I have a column for count(distinct TA_STUDENT_ID) which calculates the correct count.  I then have 2 additional columns in which I am doing a count by TA_LOCATION and the totals for the numbers on each row under TA_LOCATION need to add up to the COUNT of the DISTINCT TA_STUDENT_ID.  I need help to get it to do that.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
count  (distinct TA_STUDENT_ID) as 'count',
COUNT (CASE WHEN (TA_LOCATION = 'CCC') THEN 'CCC'  END) AS 'CCC',
COUNT(CASE WHEN (TA_LOCATION = 'SCCDC') THEN 'SCCDC'  END) AS 'SCCDC',      
[TA_AW_ID]
FROM  [S85_TA_ACYR]
group by   [TA_AW_ID]
order by  [TA_AW_ID]
```

My desired results are that the totals on each row in the TA_LOCATION columns should total and match the numbers on the rows in my COUNT DISTINCT TA_STUDENT_ID column.

Comment: why should the totals match? post sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` with `CASE` expression :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TA_STUDENT_ID) as 'count',
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (TA_LOCATION = 'CCC') THEN TA_STUDENT_ID  END) AS 'CCC',
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (TA_LOCATION = 'SCCDC') THEN TA_STUDENT_ID  END) AS 'SCCDC',      
       [TA_AW_ID]
FROM  [S85_TA_ACYR]
GROUP BY [TA_AW_ID]
ORDER BY [TA_AW_ID];
```

Comment: Just a note for the OP. The counts might still not match if a student_id is present in both locations.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!  I originally had distinct case when's but would only get '1's - I see now that I needed to also add in THEN TA_STUDENT_ID...Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a SUM() for the second two fields, like this:

```
SELECT
    Count = COUNT(DISTINCT TA_STUDENT_ID)
    ,CCC = SUM(CASE WHEN ( TA_LOCATION = 'CCC' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,SCCDC = SUM(CASE WHEN ( TA_LOCATION = 'SCCDC' ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,TA_AW_ID
FROM S85_TA_ACYR
GROUP BY TA_AW_ID
ORDER BY TA_AW_ID
```